# Titration of a polyprotic acid with a strong base

Tags: acid-base, titration

My book says:

> in the titration of a polyprotic acid we have more than one equivalence point which represents the neutralization of each step of the acid ionized.

The reaction might be:

$$\ce{H2CO3 + NaOH -> NaHCO3 + H2O}$$

$$\ce{NaHCO3 + NaOH -> Na2CO3 + H2O}$$

Now my questions are:

> 1. Why does the reaction of second step in the ionization of acid
>    does not start until its first step has been consumed totally?
> 2. Even if it does (may be), why we do not consider it?

I think of a possible answer, which I have applied to and got fairly well results. I think It might be that the reaction of multiple steps proceed simultaneously but we can, in a good manner, break up all these steps into independent ones such that they start only after the previous one has completely taken, and do calculations with it, and then make it overlap such that it remains the same as it was.

I call this the "Overlapping of Independent steps to work simultaneously".
Is it a correct method to think of?

Comment: My guess is that it is more energetically favorable for the first reaction to occur than the second.

Comment: 1. Avoid over-formatting your text. It is barely readable. I have edited your question 2. "My book says:" What book?

Comment: Each acid ionization step is an equilibrium reaction, involving pH. This topic is described in many ways on many places. Search.

Comment: See e.g. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Acids_and_Bases/Monoprotic_Versus_Polyprotic_Acids_And_Bases/Polyprotic_Acids_And_Bases

Comment: @KeSHAW. In my opinion, the question (1) has no meaning, because the word "not" should be removed from this question (1). I would rewrite here your question (1) :  "Why does the reaction of second step in the ionization of acid does start until its first step has been consumed totally?" Do you see what I mean ?